# When are the following inclusions $\subsetneq$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

When does the "equality" part of inclusion fail in:

$$\overline{A \cap B} \subseteq \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$$
and
$$Int(A \cup B) \supseteq Int(A) \cup Int(B)$$

?

Can you provide an simple example?

**P.S.**
We are working in metric space $(X,d)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\overline{(0,1) \cap (1,2)}=\overline{\emptyset}=\emptyset$

While we have $\overline{(0,1)}\cap \overline{(1,2)}=[0,1]\cap[1,2]=\{1\}$

Also: $Int([0,1]\cup[1,2])=(0,2)$ and $Int([0,1])\cup Int([1,2])=(0,1)\cup(1,2)$